# Userscript too big for Tampermonkey's integrated editor

Tags: javascript, userscripts, tampermonkey

After someone's genius idea to make it impossible to load userscripts from local files, the only way to update tampermonkey script is to copy it from the file and paste it in the integrated editor.

Because that's just stupid, I wrote myself a script that does that automatically, passing the scripts to tampermonkey through a local HTTP server.

However, my current userscript - compiled with webpack - is so big that the integrated editor freezes for 30 seconds when the script is pasted (both manually and automatically) or when I just open it.

What can I do to deal with this limitation? Is there a way to get Tampermonkey to update a script without opening the integrated editor?

Comment: I use `@require file://.......js` for locally developed scripts so only the metadata block is present in TM. In Chrome you need to enable "Allow file access" checkbox in chrome://extensions details page for TM.

Comment: Does Violentmonkey have the same limitiations? I really don't know, otherwise might be worth giving that a try instead of TM?